# How do you extract a file using tar in AIX?

Tags: linux, unix, tar, aix

On a NORMAL Unix distro, `tar zxvf` works but seems like my machine has some super old version of tar that doesn't have the right parameters.

```
-bash-3.00$ tar zxvf qemu-1.7.0.tar.bz2
Usage: tar -{c|r|t|u|x} [ -BdDEFhilmopRUsvw ] [ -Number ] [ -f TarFile ]
           [ -b Blocks ] [ -S [ Feet ] | [ Feet@Density ] | [ Blocksb ] ]
           [ -L InputList ] [-X ExcludeFile] [ -N Blocks ] [ -C Directory ] File ...
Usage: tar {c|r|t|u|x} [ bBdDEfFhilLXmNopRsSUvw[0-9] ] ]
           [ Blocks ] [ TarFile ] [ InputList ] [ ExcludeFile ] 
           [ [ Feet ] | [ Feet@Density ] | [ Blocksb ] ] [-C Directory ] File ...
```

**How should I untar my .tar.bz given this verison of tar on an AIX machine?**

```
-bash-3.00$ tar xvf qemu-1.7.0.tar.bz2
tar: 0511-169 A directory checksum error on media; 0 not equal to 71773.
```

Comment: It's a bz2 file, try tar xvf ...

Comment: ah... blind....

Answer (score 0):

Check out your .bz2 document support in your `man tar`. If none is specified, you might not know how is `tar` interpreting the document uncompress proceeding.

Further, that directory checksum error might be (not very likely?) to be solvable if you build by yourself an up to date version of `tar`. You are trying to open with an older-than-ancient `tar` a .tar document created with an up to date `tar`. This is just one possibility, maybe you want another solution, like:

You could uncompress the .tar.bz2 document in an up to date host and then pass it to the AIX machine from it or to it using the `rsync` command from either the hosts (the one you get working first?).